# How to query db files in SQL server, not use cache?

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to check database files integrity. Files of a database are available and correct, database is online and healthy, but it can still happen that the database cannot access the files and fails if a query which returns from cache is run.

There are queries like Checkpoint, dbcc checkdb, checktable etc which can be used to confirm if everything is healthy. But I cannot make use of these queries due to some scenarios where they fail or take too much time to execute.

I am looking for any query that we can run on a database, that ends up making use of db files, and not the cache or any other way to establish that the db has not lost access to files. This will help in confirming that the database was able to successfully access the db files. The database is extra large in size, in TBs.

Answer (score 4):

> but it can still happen that the database cannot access the files and fails if a query which doesn't return from cache is run

If I understand what you're saying, this is incorrect. If the database files themselves (presumably the MDF and LDF) are offline, it doesn't matter that there was cached data in Memory, you still won't be able to access the objects of that database or query anything from it. All queries against that database would fail, even if all of the data is cached in Memory.

Regardless of what you do, you definitely need to be running `DBCC CHECKDB` routinely to verify both the physical and logical integrity of your database. As already pointed out, you won't be able to emulate that otherwise, and you don't want to be on the hook for database corruption which can occur and live dormant for a while, with the database still online appearing ok, when in reality it's not. Without realizing it, you could go a long time with your backups of your database also containing the corruption too, and then you may be in bigger trouble. Running `DBCC CHECKDB` is an online operation, so it shouldn't matter much how long it takes to complete, as long as your server is provisioned enough such that it isn't causing resource contention.

You'd be better off monitoring the `state` of your databases instead of the physical files themselves, since the `state` will be inclusive of the use case of the physical files going offline. You can do so using the [`sys.databases`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) system view like this:

```
SELECT 
    [name] AS DatabaseName,
    [state] AS DatabaseState
FROM sys.databases;
```

Essentially anything with a `state` that isn't `0` should be of concern / interest to you (all of the values and their meanings are listed in the previously linked docs). And if one of your databases isn't in that list, then you have bigger problems, as someone / something likely dropped that database from your server. You can run this adhoc or schedule a job that runs this (I'd recommend in the context of the `master` database) periodically.

Outside of that, you may want to invest in a monitoring tool which can stay external of the database and will let you know if the databases go offline. There's a multitude out there, but to name a few (in no particular order):

- (SolarWinds) SentryOne SQL Sentry
- Red Gate SQL Monitor
- Quest Spotlight
- IDERA SQL Diagnostic Manager.

Comment: Sorry typo
but it can still happen that the database cannot access the files and fails if a query which **returns** from cache is run

Comment: Clearly the best answer, eluding Supervision and Maintenance tasks by altering the way SQL Server works is not a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you will have such problems, you will see error messages left and right without having to run any query. Whatever solution you use for monitoring should send you alerts once error messages appear (ERRORLOG or Windows Event Viewer Logs). If you are not seeing any error messages, you can safely asume the database is online.

You can run sp_helpdb to do a very basic access check and, if you want to be extra sure, you can create a dummy table and insert a row every time you want to check, but monitoring is the way to go to be alerted as soon as something happens and not rely on a weekly access check.

Also, nothing can replace dbcc checkdb to reliably check the integrity. The above will not throw errors if you have inconsistencies in your tables.

Answer (score 1):

> .... Checkpoint, dbcc checkdb, checktable etc ... I cannot make use of these queries due to some scenarios where they fail or take too much time to execute.

Unfortunately, these are *exactly* the tools that you *need* to use.

> I am looking for any query that we can run on a database, that ends up making use of db files, and not the cache ...

You misunderstand how your database works.
Just about *every* query goes through the Cache.
Most (if not *all*) of the time your database is running, its database files are *inconsistent*; taking a copy of them would get you *rubbish*.  Only the DBMS, using its transaction logs, can piece them back together again into a consistent state (or you shut the database down, at which point the datafiles are made consistent).

> ... or any other way to establish that the db has not lost access to files.

Short of querying every row in every table, there isn't any way to do this.

Out of interest, *why* do you feel the need to do this?

Are your database files mounted on *non-local* disks? (*Very* Bad Idea, BTW)

Comment: Yes the db files are not present on local disks, they are remotely present and made available through file sharing, which is why I want to have a way to make sure the access to these files is not lost via connectivity issues or something else.

Comment: As I said, this is a Very Bad Idea.   
Your datafiles should be as "close" to the running DBMS software as possible - the two really should be treated as an /inseparable/ unit (keeping the two separate is only done nowadays by the likes of MS Access!).  With the setup you have /any/ network disruption could cause massive problems for your application, service outages and data corruption, /all/ of which are Your Problem and /none/ of which you want to be dealing with on a regular basis.  
Save yourself a lot of heartache and relocate those datafiles!

Comment: Question: J.D. mentioned above that if the disk is offline, no matter the caching, any query should fail. You mentioned that just about every query goes through the Cache and files are mostly inconsistent. I am not very clear if the files will have impact on all queries we run(like even on a SELECT)
We have a use case where the disk went offline and sys.databases still returned that the db was online which is opposite to what J.D. said. Nice to have some clarity on this